Array() displaying in all pages of admin -view page source
When we check view source page of our site, it is displaying below code in all pages :
Array
(
)

below is screenshot :

Requirement :
How to remove that Array() text ? From which file it is coming from ?

It might be added during development, most probably coming from Theme or Plugin, The best way to debug is download active plugins and active theme using this plugin Download Plugin/ Theme, and open code in VSCode and search for var_dump, var_export, print_r, die, and etc.
I'd say first search in Theme than go for Plugins.

I can see in thousands of lines when we search in vs code. is there any idea in which file it will be ? as because it is displaying in header ?

I guess no, but you can find the culprit by switching theme if Array disappears, and deactivate plugins one by one and see which makes it disappear, once you find one, download and search in that one.

when i rename the theme through filezilla, the "array()" text gone.

Problem seems to be in the theme, but do try deactivating Plugins as well, but keep theme active.

is there any other word that i need to try apart from : "die , var_dump, var_export" ?   ?

we installed 20 plugins, as when i renamed the theme name , the "array" text disappeared

Also search for print_r and Array.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
